# In Active Record, how to find nil nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have many photos that belong to `Movie` like `Movie.photos`. Some movies have photos some other not.

How can easily find all the movies with no photos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this method in your Movie model

```
def self.no_photos
  Movie.all.reject{|movie| movie.photos}
end
```

You can use it this way.

`movies_with_no_photos = Movie.no_photos`

Comment: That should be def self.no_photos or Movie.no_photos since it's a class method, right? Also, movie.photos will return [], not nil, so you should probably check size > 0 or something like that.

Comment: That's correct. I simply end up using `Movie.all.reject{|movie| movie.photos.first}`